# littleproxy on Android devices how to get it to work

Tags: java, android, proxy, http-proxy

I have been trying to run littleproxy from my Android app. Below, you will find the code.

Before publishing this post, I searched through StackOverflow and the web for information on running littleproxy on Android devices. I could not find answers to my questions below. There is very little information about littleproxy on Android.

On my test Android phone, a Huawei Mate 20 Pro running Androind 9, I enabled proxy manually on the Wifi network I am using as follows:

Proxy hostname - 127.0.0.1
Proxy port - 8100

The logs posted by littleproxy are as follows:

```
03-20 18:46:48.345: I/DefaultHttpProxyServer(27269):  - withAddress - /127.0.0.1:8100
03-20 18:46:48.547: I/DefaultHttpProxyServer(27269): Starting proxy at address: {} - /127.0.0.1:8100
03-20 18:46:48.549: D/ServerGroup(27269): Initializing thread pools for {} with {} 
acceptor threads, {} incoming worker threads, and {} outgoing worker threads - TCP - 2 - 8 - 8
03-20 18:46:48.558: I/DefaultHttpProxyServer(27269): Proxy listening with TCP transport
03-20 18:46:48.589: I/DefaultHttpProxyServer(27269): Proxy started at address: {} - /127.0.0.1:8100
```

After proxy starts as the above logs seem to indicate, I try to access a (any) site on the web and I am unable to do so.

Based on the code (below), the only sites I should not be able to access are ones like
http://httpbin.org/image/png

I have four questions/issues I hope someone can help me answer:

1. Is setting the address of the proxy server on an Android device to 127.0.0.1 allowed? If not what can it be set to? Can I use port 8100, or is there a preset port I should be using (e.g. 8080) (I don't think so, just checking to make sure)?
2. How can I check whether the littleproxy proxy server is running after I start it (see code below)? Do I need to add code to ensure that it keep running?
3. Is the littleproxy start call (see code below) correct?
4. Does anyone have a successful experience of running a local proxy on an Android device without rooting the device? If yes, what's the proxy application used?

Thanks for any help in addressing these issues.

## Code which calls littleproxy from main activity

```
    Log.i(TAG, " - onCreate - About to run BlockingFilterProxy.main(args) --- ");

        String[] args = new String[1];

        BlockingFilterProxy.main(args);

    Log.i(TAG, " - onCreate - Returned from BlockingFilterProxy.main(args) --- ");
```

## BlockingFilterProxy code

```
package com.android.contextq.gatekeepertolltaker.proxy.filters;

import android.util.Log;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Date;

import org.littleshoot.proxy.HttpFilters;
import org.littleshoot.proxy.HttpFiltersAdapter;
import org.littleshoot.proxy.HttpFiltersSource;
import org.littleshoot.proxy.HttpFiltersSourceAdapter;
import org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer;
import org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ProxyUtils;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultFullHttpResponse;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObject;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseStatus;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion;

/**
 * Blocks access to URLs ending in "png" or "jpeg" and returns a 502 response. 
 * 
 * Test URLs - HTTP  : http://httpbin.org/image/png
 *             HTTPS : https://httpbin.org/image/png
 */
public class BlockingFilterProxy {

private static String TAG = "BlockingFilterProxy";
private static final int PORT = 8100;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HttpFiltersSource filtersSource = getFiltersSource();

    DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
            .withAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8100))
//                .withAddress(new InetSocketAddress("10.125.24.28",8100))
//        .withPort(PORT)
    .withAllowLocalOnly(false)
    .withFiltersSource(filtersSource)
    .withName("BlockingFilterProxy")
    .start();
}

private static HttpFiltersSource getFiltersSource() {
    return new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter(){

        @Override
        public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest) {

            return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest){

                @Override
                public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {

                    if(httpObject instanceof HttpRequest){
                        HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) httpObject;

                        Log.i(TAG, "Method URI : " + request.getMethod() + " " + request.getUri());

                        if(request.getUri().endsWith("png") || request.getUri().endsWith("jpeg")){
                            //For URLs ending in 'png' and 'jpeg', return a 502 response.
                            return getBadGatewayResponse();
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                private HttpResponse getBadGatewayResponse() {
                    String body = "<!DOCTYPE HTML \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n"
                            + "<html><head>\n"
                            + "<title>"+"Bad Gateway"+"</title>\n"
                            + "</head><body>\n"
                            + "An error occurred"
                            + "</body></html>\n";
                    byte[] bytes = body.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    ByteBuf content = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(bytes);
                    HttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.BAD_GATEWAY, content);
                    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, bytes.length);
                    response.headers().set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
                    response.headers().set("Date", ProxyUtils.formatDate(new Date()));
                    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, "close");
                    return response;
                    }                   
                };
            }           
        };
    }
}
```